# C# dictionary value reference type - please explain why this happens

Tags: c#, dictionary, pass-by-reference

I don't understand the results of the following linqpad query in C#. The comments should explain where I am confused.

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string, testClass> test = new Dictionary<string, testClass>();

    string key = "key";
    testClass val = null;

    test.Add(key, val);

    val = new testClass();

    test[key].Dump(); //returns null.   WHAT? I just set it!!!



    test[key] = val;
    val.Text = "something";
    //  returns val object, with Text set to "Something". 
    //  If the above didn't work, why does this work?
    test[key].Dump(); 



    val.Text = "Nothing";
    //  return val object, with Text set to "Nothing". 
    //  This, I expect, but, again, why didn't the first example work?
    test[key].Dump(); 



    val = null;
    //  returns val object, with Text set to "Nothing"...WHAT?? 
    //  Now my head is going to explode...
    test[key].Dump(); 

}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class testClass
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }

    public string Text { get; set;}     
}
```

Comment: you are setting val to null then adding it?

Comment: Answer to all your confusions is that a reference itself is a value-type variable that is actually **copied** to the argument when sent in a function call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main reason is that the variable (`val`) is not the object.  It merely contains a reference to an object (or null).

`testClass val = null` declares a variable of type `testClass` and sets it to null.  It doesn't point to any object.

`test.Add(key, val)` adds an entry in the dictionary that points to null (note: it *doesn't* point to `val` nor does it point to any object).

`val = new testClass();` creates a *new* instance of `testClass` and `val` now points to that new object.  `test[key]` *is still null* and doesn't point to any object.

```
test[key] = val;
val.Text = "something";
test[key].Dump();
```

This code points `test[key]` to the same object that `val` points to.  Again note *is it not pointing to `val`*.  When you change the object with `val.Text = "something"` you can see the change using `test[key].Dump()` because they both point to the same object.

```
val.Text = "Nothing";
test[key].Dump();
```

When you set `val.Text` to the string "Nothing" you can see the change through `test[key]` for the same reason as above, *they both point to the same object*.

```
val = null;
test[key].Dump();
```

This code sets `val` to point at null.  `test[key]` *still* points at the object.  Now `val` and `test[key]` point to different things.

Answer (score 7):

```
test.Add(key, val);
val = new testClass();
test[key].Dump(); //returns null.   WHAT? I just set it!!!
```

You are re-instantiating `val`.  It is no longer pointing to the same object that you added to `test`.  When you new up a reference object, it points to a brand new object.

---

If, say, you had an `int` property on `testClass` and did:

```
var c = new testClass{ MyProperty = 1}
test.Add(key, c);

c.MyProperty = 2;
test[key].MyProperty.Dump();
```

you *would* see `2` outputted, because you didn't change the object that `c` is pointing to, but altered a property on the existing object.

Comment: Can you add a link to the documentation on "re-instantiation" in C#? I'm not familiar with that one.

Comment: @EdPlunkett re-instantiation in this context means instantiating again. Nothing different than instantiation.

Comment: @Krishna I'm suggesting, delicately, that when you're talking to a very confused new programmer, it's not a very good idea to use bizarre, deliberately misleading, novel terminology that you just made up off the top of your head. "Re-instantiation" in this or any other C#-related context means nothing at all, and most uninformed guesses about what it *might* mean will lead a confused newbie further astray. The value of `val` was null. He's "re-instantiating" null? That's malicious gibberish.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I wouldn't call obvious sarcasm a 'delicate suggestion'.  I use the term daily in my work, and I certainly wouldn't call it `bizarre, deliberately misleading, novel terminology`.  If you can't put a common prefix hyphened before a word into context, then you'll certainly have problems in our field.

Answer (score 3):

```
testClass val = null;

test.Add(key, val);
```

`val` refers to `null`. You just added a `null` to your dictionary, under the key `key`.

```
val = new testClass();
```

You just assigned a new instance of `testClass` to your variable named `val`. The dictionary has no way of knowing that you did that. It doesn't know about `val`; all you gave it was the value that `val` held at that time. Think of it as keeping a copy of what `val` held then.

**If you put write "4" on a piece of paper and take a photo of it, then you erase it and write "5", the photo still shows "4".**

```
test[key].Dump(); //returns null.   WHAT? I just set it!!!
```

You set `test[key]` to `null`, two lines ago. `test[key]` isn't a reference to "whatever `val` refers to now"; it's whatever value you passed to the `Dictionary.Add()` method. That value was `null`. The dictionary keeps exactly what you gave it, until you give it something else.

```
test[key] = val;
```

OK, *now* you gave it something else. You gave it the new value of `val`.

```
val.Text = "something";
//  returns val object, with Text set to "Something". 
//  If the above didn't work, why does this work?
test[key].Dump();
```

...and that's why this works.

```
val.Text = "Nothing";
//  return val object, with Text set to "Nothing". 
//  This, I expect, but, again, why didn't the first example work?
test[key].Dump();
```

The dictionary still has that new value of `val` -- and `val` is still referring to that same object (think of it as hanging in space, off the shoulder of Orion). And now you've altered one of the properties of that one object that they both happen to be referring to.

```
val = null;
```

Whoops, they're not both referring to the same object any more. The dictionary is still referring to that object, but `val` is now referring to nothing at all.

```
//  returns val object, with Text set to "Nothing"...WHAT?? 
//  Now my head is going to explode...
test[key].Dump();
```

And you still haven't given the dictionary anything new, so it still has the last thing you gave it.

Don't feel too bad about this. I taught C# last year to my brother, an MIT PhD in electrical engineering. He got badly snarled in this same issue -- and he's the guy who patiently taught how pointers work in C, back in 1995.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to explain it in code comments:

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string, testClass> test = new Dictionary<string, testClass>();

    string key = "key";
    testClass val = null;
    //val now holds a null reference

    test.Add(key, val);
    //You add a null reference to the dictionary

    val = new testClass();
    //Now val holds a new reference for testClass, while the dictionary still has null

    test[key].Dump(); //returns null.   WHAT? I just set it!!!
    //Now it returns the null reference which you just added to the dictionary


    test[key] = val;
    //Now the dictionary holds the same reference as val

    val.Text = "something";
    //You set the Text of the val, and the dictionary-held value, because they're the same

    //  returns val object, with Text set to "Something". 
    //  If the above didn't work, why does this work?
    test[key].Dump(); 
    // I think now you know why..

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following code:

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>();
SomeFunc(lst);
```

Here is SomeFunc():

```
void SomeFunc(List<int> l)
{
  l = null;
}
```

Calling `SomeFunc()` will not change the value of variable `lst` in any way. This is because `l` gets a copy of `lst`. Thus both `lst` and `l` point to the same memory object, but both are distinct themselves and changing the contents of one variable has no effect on the value of other.

In a way you can think of reference types as classical pointers, although they are different in many important ways. Having two pointer pointing to the same object doesn't mean those two pointers have any effect on each other's value, and setting one of them to a different value (or null) doesn't change the value of other.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware of the difference of value and reference types.

In this case, you have a reference variable with the name val, it's address to the object in the memory is null.
When you are calling "test.Add(key, val);" and val equals null, then there is object behind this reference variable.
In the next line, you initialize the reference variable, now there is a object behind it.

So these results make absolutely sense.

Look here for more information:
[Value and Reference Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

C# uses reference types for objects.

1)In the first example you are adding a pair of key and a value which is a reference type. The reference is pointing to null so you actually add (key,null).

2) Now you have created an instance of an object. The val is referencing that object and when you assign it test[key] = val you are actually assigning the object that the val is referencing.

3)The object referenced in the dictionary and the val variable is the same . So you are accessing the same object.

4)You have set the val to null so it doesn't reference anything but in the dictionary it is still referencing to that old object you have created.