# How to add multiple objects list inside a list

Tags: c#, list, object, reference-type

When I add an object in `bCPList` after looping, all records become same as the last object inserted. Why's that happening and how could I solve this?

```
public List<Entity.BCPToolkitWorkplace> Load_work_Place(List<BCPToolkitWorkplace> bCPToolkit)
{
    Entity.BCPToolkitWorkplace bCP = new Entity.BCPToolkitWorkplace();
    List< Entity.BCPToolkitWorkplace> bCPList = new List<Entity.BCPToolkitWorkplace>();

    foreach (var item in bCPToolkit)
    {
        bCP.txn_type = item.txn_type;
        bCP.workplace_id = item.workplace_id;
        bCP.workplace_name = item.workplace_name;
        bCP.workplace_number = item.workplace_number;
        bCPList.Add(bCP);
    }

    return bCPList;
}
```

Comment: Please be specific: which language: Java? C#? It certainly not about both

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Add the creation of the object inside the foreach loop. Now you're changing the same object and adding it to the list over and over again. But since it's a reference there's only 1 object behind the scene's that you keep changing.

Comment: It's absolutely logical for reference types.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the BCP object inside the loop as follows

```
public List< Entity.BCPToolkitWorkplace> Load_work_Place(List< BCPToolkitWorkplace> bCPToolkit)
        {

            List< Entity.BCPToolkitWorkplace> bCPList = new List< Entity.BCPToolkitWorkplace>();

            foreach (var item in bCPToolkit)
            {
                // Declaring the bcp object inside the loop
                Entity.BCPToolkitWorkplace bCP = new Entity.BCPToolkitWorkplace();
                bCP.txn_type = item.txn_type;
                bCP.workplace_id = item.workplace_id;
                bCP.workplace_name = item.workplace_name;
                bCP.workplace_number = item.workplace_number;
                bCPList.Add(bCP);
            }

            return bCPList;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move this line to the inside of the `foreach`.

```
Entity.BCPToolkitWorkplace bCP = new Entity.BCPToolkitWorkplace();
```

The reason this is happening is that `Entity.BCPToolkitWorkplace`, apparently is defined as a class (reference-type), and you defined only one instance of that class at the top, so you were technically adding the same exact instance to the list over and over.

Take a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36225847/3602352) for more about how reference types work.